# css calc divide gives wrong number

Tags: css

This seems pretty strange.  I'm putting the following on a div:

```
width: calc(702px / 672);
```

And I get:

```
width: 1.03125px
```

If you put this 702 / 672 into a calculator though, you'll end up with

```
1.0446
```

Which is close, but not nearly close enough.

Why do I need this?  I'm building a fluid layout that resizes things like icons/images/margins etc as the page resizes, using LESS to give me an appropriate `calc` based on my px-based figma src. The full equation is:

```
/** linear interpolate value from small to big as screen goes from small-size to big-size */
.scalable-unit(@property, @small, @big, @unit) {
  @{property}: clamp(
      unit(@small, @unit),
      calc(unit(@small, @unit) + (@big - @small) * ((100vw - @tabletBreakpoint) / (@desktopWidth - @tableWidth))),
      unit(@big, @unit),
    );
}
```

Funnily enough, it works for px-based values, just not %age based ones.  If I put in the size of my image directly

```
.scalable(width, 105, 174, px)
```

then I end up with the right size on my desktop breakpoint.  But if I use % size, then I get the wrong output.

```
.scalable(width, 75, 100, %)
```

Comment: in CSS +/-1px will not make a visual difference so 0.01 will not do either.

Comment: If you want to create a fluid layout, I would recommend using responsive CSS units such as vw, vh, rem, or % that update based on the current screen size instead of pixels, if possible

Comment: @TemaniAfif true, but this isn't the whole equation here.  It's just the bit that doesn't work

Comment: @RyanMillares Those units can't help me if I want to shrink my padding from 50px at 1000px to 15px at 500px.  For example, the value for 50px at 1000px is 5vw, but at 500px it's 3vw.

Comment: Although I agree that OP doesn't use the best approach, the question is still interesting

Comment: I get 1.0375px (Windows10 Edge). What browser/system are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth - Interesting!  I believe I checked in Firefox, Opera, and possibly chrome.  I'll re-check in edge once the current PR is done

Comment: @flppv - I thought there should be a better way out there somewhere already, but I've not found anything.  Do you know another technique to achieve what I want?  Ideally, I should be able to scale the site up & down with no (minimal anyway) popping

Comment: Could you put up a complete example? So we can see the difference between px and % calculation.